# AWS QueryRequest not returning any values from secondary index query

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

So I am trying to query one of my dynamoDB tables and for some reason it is not returning any results.  I have another user table that has almost the exact same index and it returns a value.  Here is my code:

```
String fbId = requestInfo.get("requestFbId");
        System.out.println("The id is " + fbId);



Map<String, AttributeValue> exAttributeVal = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
        exAttributeVal.put(":val", new AttributeValue().withS(fbId));

        QueryRequest friendsQuery = new QueryRequest()
                .withTableName(Keys.friendsTable)
                .withIndexName("User-Friends-index")
                .withKeyConditionExpression("userId = :val")
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(exAttributeVal);

        QueryResult friendsQueryResult = dynamoDbClient.query(friendsQuery);

        System.out.println("The size is " + friendsQueryResult.getItems().size());

        for (int i = 0; i < friendsQueryResult.getItems().size(); i++) {

            System.out.println("The result is " + friendsQueryResult.getItems().get(i));

        }
```

Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong here? This also used to work directly on my android app, but it is not working now that I have moved it into lambda

Comment: Is the function itself getting an error? Or it is running fine and it's just your query result that is empty? I'm wondering if you have an IAM issue where your Lambda function does not have permissions to query your DynamoDB table.

Comment: It runs fine and the query result is empty.  The value is stored as a string value and everything.

Comment: Something must have been wrong with my table. I just made a new one, transferred the data and now it works

Comment: Great to hear that!